# Finding the unique differences between two arrays of different length in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Please, how do I compare the two arrays if they are equal disregarding duplicated numbers? Then output the unique compared values and the uniquely different values.

### This is my array

$a1 = array(1, 2, 9, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7); 
$a2 = array(1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2 );

### my expected outputs:

compared values = 1,2,4,5,7,9 
differences = 3,6 
output = false

I have tried $a1 == $a2 
I have also tried various ways, they don't just get it right.

Comment: You'll have to loop over each of the elements. What "various ways" have you tried, and what was the issue?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-diff.php

Comment: what is output = false? What determines that? Whether they contain the same distinct set of elements?

Comment: This question is asking multiple (duplicate) questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok then... I'll at least write something leveraging the plethora of PHP array functions...

```
<?php

$a1 = array(1, 2, 9, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7); 
$a2 = array(1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2);

$diff = array_diff($a2, $a1);

sort($a1);

echo 'compared values = ' . implode(",", array_unique($a1)) . '<br>'; 
echo 'differences = ' . implode(",", array_unique($diff)) . '<br>';
//?
$output = (empty($diff)) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo 'output = ' . $output;
```

> compared values = 1,2,4,5,7,9
>
> differences = 3,6
>
> output = false

Comment: Hmm, your answer makes me wonder if I misinterpreted what they meant by "compared values". I assumed the diff would need to go both ways since they're wanting to use it to check for "equality", but maybe not.

Comment: I wasn't sure. Not really clear from the question. Went as literal(?) as I could. I think your answer is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

For disregarding duplicated numbers, start by running each array through `array_unique`.

```
$a1 = array_unique($a1);
$a2 = array_unique($a2);
```

You can assign the unique arrays to new variables if you need to keep the original values.

Now, finding the elements in common is easy:

```
$compared_values = array_intersect($a1, $a2);
```

But finding the differences is *a little* tricky. `array_diff` returns values from its first argument that aren't present in the subsequent arguments. So it may return a different result depending on the order of arguments. (For example, the result of `array_diff([1], [1, 2, 3]);` will be an empty array.)

To be sure to get the full diff, you can merge the results of doing it both ways.

```
$differences = array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2), array_diff($a2, $a1));
```

To see if the two arrays contained the same distinct set of values, you can just evaluate `$differences` as boolean. If it's empty, it will evaluate as false, and vice versa.

```
$output = !$differences;
```

Negating it like this will implicitly cast it to boolean, so it will be `false` if there were any differences and true if it's empty.

The way you tried, `$a1 == $a2` can't work because [array equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) in PHP means the two arrays have the same key/value pairs. Duplicated values and different orders (hence different keys) will prevent them from being equal.

Comment: I don't understand why the other answer was accepted. This answer is more comprehensive and offers to check unique items across both arrays instead of just from one. I personally was trying to find a way to compare an existing array to a newly submitted one and only pull the 'new' items to run code against and this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty ugly code, much like I made a proof of concept for you, I'll let you optimise to suit your needs. This will give you your expected results. I hope it helps. * I just assumed that output = false when the arrays aren't identical. Feel free to tell me if i'm wrong.

```
//Array 1
$a1 = array(1, 2, 9, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7); 
//Array 2
$a2 = array(1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2 );

//To get your example results, they need to be sorted and the duplicates removed.
$a1 = array_unique($a1);
$a2 = array_unique($a2);
sort($a1);
sort($a2);
//Get smaller array as array1
$array1 = (sizeof($a1) > sizeof($a2)) ? $a1:$a2;
//Get bigger array as array2
$array2 = (sizeof($a1) < sizeof($a2)) ? $a1:$a2;
//Check the difference between each.
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);


echo "Compared values = " . implode(',', array_intersect($a1, $a2)).PHP_EOL;
echo "differences = " . implode(',', $diff).PHP_EOL;
echo "output = " . (($diff) ? "false" : "true");
```